# Hibernate: migrating from 3.6.9 to 4.2

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I'm using spring and hibernate.
Hibernate 4.2 declares `Ejb3Configuration` class as deprecated and it has no method **getEventListeners** which lets to setup listeners. This class used to get `EntityManagerFactory`.

I'm using it to make database audition (logging of update, insert, delete events). How i should get EntityManagerFactory with audition configuration?

```
public class HibernateExtendedPersistenceProvider extends HibernatePersistence {

    private PostInsertEventListener[] postInsertEventListeners;
    private PostUpdateEventListener[] postUpdateEventListeners;
    private PostDeleteEventListener[] postDeleteEventListeners;

    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    @Override
    public EntityManagerFactory createEntityManagerFactory(String persistenceUnitName, Map properties) {
        Ejb3Configuration cfg = new Ejb3Configuration();
        setupConfiguration(cfg);
        Ejb3Configuration configured = cfg.configure( persistenceUnitName, properties );
        return configured != null ? configured.buildEntityManagerFactory() : null;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    @Override
    public EntityManagerFactory createContainerEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceUnitInfo info, Map properties) {
        Ejb3Configuration cfg = new Ejb3Configuration();
        setupConfiguration(cfg);
        Ejb3Configuration configured = cfg.configure( info, properties );
        return configured != null ? configured.buildEntityManagerFactory() : null;
    }

    private void setupConfiguration(Ejb3Configuration cfg) {
        // 4.2: Ejb3Configuration deprecated and has no method getEventListeners
        cfg.getEventListeners().setPostInsertEventListeners(postInsertEventListeners); 
        cfg.getEventListeners().setPostDeleteEventListeners(postDeleteEventListeners);
        cfg.getEventListeners().setPostUpdateEventListeners(postUpdateEventListeners);
    }

    public void setPostInsertEventListeners(PostInsertEventListener[] postInsertEventListeners) {
        this.postInsertEventListeners = postInsertEventListeners;
    }

    public void setPostUpdateEventListeners(PostUpdateEventListener[] postUpdateEventListeners) {
        this.postUpdateEventListeners = postUpdateEventListeners;
    }

    public void setPostDeleteEventListeners(PostDeleteEventListener[] postDeleteEventListeners) {
        this.postDeleteEventListeners = postDeleteEventListeners;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use the JPA `EntityListener` annotation? I believe they serve the same purpose.

Comment: Can you give example?

Answer (score 0):

If you have controll over the sourcecode i would take a look at hibernate envers. It does a good job in versioning. It not just an audittrail like updated but keeps track of the old entity versions.

The JPA entity listener api has the disadvantage that you have no easy access to the original values before the changes. You will have to get these values from somewhere to create deltas.

You can still register your hibernate event listeners but the recommended way is now to use SPI. Check out Hibernate Integrator to see how its done.